# Complexity of Code Snippet Without Knowing A Function?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I have the code snippet:

```
int const n = 300;
int nArr[n];
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
   if(i >x)
     copyPrevious(nArr,i);
}
```

I need to find the complexity for the cases when x = 300 and x = 5.

I have already reasoned that the x = 300 case will give O(n) complexity, based on n + 2 assignments, since it never enters the if statement.

However, for 5, I am a little confused. This time, the if statement is relevant, and I don't know how to handle it, since I don't know the particulars of the copyPrevious function. The only thing I know about it is that it itself has complexity O(n).

My usual approach is to make a table of the different parts of the code and the assignments that occur inside and outside the loops. Obviously, the for loop assigns i++ a total of n times, but what of the copyPrevious function? How do I treat it in this manner when I know only a particular x and its complexity?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What yould you obtain if you replaced the opaque `copyPrevious` with an obvious $O(n)$ line such as `for(int j=0; j<n; j++) dummy++;`?

Comment: Ahh, good point! I think I see now.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `copyPrevious(arr,i)` has a running time of $O(i)=Ci$ for some constant $C>0$. Basically, you are trying to compute:
$$ \begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1+\sum_{i=x+1}^{n-1}Ci
&= n +C[(x+1)+(x+2)+\cdots+(n-1)] \\
&= n+C \left[\dfrac{n-x-1}{2}(x+n) \right]  \\
&= n+C \left[\dfrac{n-5-1}{2}(5+n) \right]  \\
&= n+\dfrac{C}{2} (n-6)(n+5)  \\
&= n+\dfrac{C}{2} (n^2-n-30)  \\
&= \dfrac{C}{2}n^2 + \left(1-\dfrac{C}{2} \right)n -\dfrac{C}{2}30  \\
&= O(n^2)\\
\end{align*}$$